# View link if depended on user rights

Tags: cakephp

I am working with CakePhp 2.x. I have three Columns:

User | Course | UserCourseRole

Each user can edit multiple courses and one course can be edited by multiple users. So far so good.

If a user wants to see an index of all the courses **i want to show a 'edit'-link only next to the courses which he can in fact edit.** 
How can i realize this? I figured i would have to set some sort of extra field inside the CourseController and check for this field inside the view. Is this the right way to go?

My current Code is

CourseController.php

```
...
public function index() {
        $courses = $this->Course->find('all', array('recursive' => 2));

         $this->set('courses', $courses);
    }
...
```

Courses/index.ctp

```
<!-- File: /app/View/Courses/index.ctp -->
...
<?php foreach ($courses as $course):?>
    ...
    <?php 
        echo $this->Html->link('edit', array('action' => 'edit', $course['Course']['id']));     
   ?>
   ...
```

Comment: [This tutorial](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/tutorials-and-examples/blog-auth-example/auth.html) has some examples of that near the end.

Answer (score 1):

In beforeRender() or beforeFilter() set $this->Auth->user() as a variable to the view, for example as userData.

```
$this->set('userData', $this->Auth->user());
```

Implement a (auth)helper that uses that variable (you can make it configurable as a helper setting) and do your checks like:

```
if ($this->Auth->hasRole($course['Course']['role']) { /* ... */ }
if ($this->Auth->isLoggedIn() { /* ... */ }
if ($this->Auth->isMe($course['Course']['user_id']) { /* ... */ }
```

Implement the hasRole() method according to whatever your specific requirements are.

Doing this as helper as a bunch of advantages, it is easy to reuse, overload and adapt to whatever your checks are and you don't use a component in a view plus that you should avoid calling statics and singletons a lot in your app. Also it is pretty easy to read and understand what the code does.

Comment: Should i do the checks within the view then?

Answer (score 0):

I think the good idea is set some variable or constans after logged (if user has privileges) and uses if statement for check.

```
if($allow === true) {  
     echo $html->link('Edit',...
}
```

or use AuthComponent::user() in Views.

This idea it's not good if we can many kind of admins (admin, moderator, reviewier, etc.)
Maybe someone will have a better solution